# Getting ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED in Chromium with both Wifi and Ethernet connected on macOS

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, google-chrome, ethernet

I have both Wifi and Ethernet connected on my Macbook Pro M1 Max (macOS Sonoma). Ethernet is higher in the service order list, so the OS should use that at all times. And for the most part it does.

However I keep getting `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` in all Chromium-based apps, like Google Chrome, Electron, Arc, Brave etc when browsing the web. It auto-corrects after a second or if I reload the page it works.

I have tried these things:

- Setting Wifi Channel to a static channel (36 or 44 for example)
- Limiting Wifi Channel width to 80mhz
- Restarting router, etc (I'm using Ubiquiti Unifi networking with multiple APs)
- Setting DNS to `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1` on both Wifi and Ethernet connections
- Restarting my laptop

Nothing works, it's completely random when it happens. Sometimes it happens 3-4 times in a minute and sometimes it happens every 1 hour etc.

The only thing that fixes the situation is turning Wifi off completely, but that disables Airdrop, Airpods, Continuity features and every other macOS feature that depends on Wifi.

My access point has both 6Ghz and 5Ghz enabled (no 2.4Ghz on this SSID), and my laptop only supports 5Ghz.

Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Comment: In my experience it’s bug with macOS Sonoma itself.

Comment: Same experience here, started happening after updating to Sonoma.

Comment: Yeah also tried using different DNS and VPN settings. Also deinstalled network adapters... nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

For me, [this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1498910) is what causes the issue. In short, my iPhone was configured as a run destination in Xcode and the manner of networking negotiation led Chrome to believe that the Network changed, throwing the above error. Removing my iPhone as a run destination instantly resolved the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU! This fixed the issue for me. I unpaired all "real" devices under Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators, and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set IPv6 to Link-Local only (unless you need IPv6). This somewhat improved it for me.

Update: As of 14.2 all issues are resolved for me.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Go to system settings. Then network. Go to details of the network (ethernet of wifi). Under ipv6, you should have the option to change to Link-Local only.

Comment: For me it's not fixed with 14.2. Disable WiFi helps for the most of the time. Not the best solution.